# How to make a view for viewmodel with single properties and list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

How can I write a View to display first some single properties (title, date, etc.), then a list of items, and finally below that, a sum, like this:

```
Title: [My shopping cart], created [Dec 1st, 2017]
[Product name] [Price]   [Quantity] [Line sum]
[Product #1]   [$ 10.00] x [1]    = [$ 10.00]
[Product #2]   [$ 13.00] x [3]    = [$ 39.00]
[Product #3]   [$ 16.00] x [2]    = [$ 32.00]
SUM                                 [$ 81.00]
```

I understand that all logic should happen either in the controller or in the model, so I'm not after any answers to do maths in the view. :)

My viewmodel looks like this:

```
public class ViewModelShoppingCart
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public List<ViewModelShoppingCartItem> ShoppingCartItems { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalSum => ShoppingCartItems.Sum(item => item.LineSum);
}

public class ViewModelShoppingCartItem
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductTitle { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal LineSum => ProductPrice * Quantity;
}
```

I'm not sure how the data of my viewmodel data is structured. In my imagination it consists of a header with some single property fields (which are not in a list), followed by a list, like so:

```
single property: Title
single property: CreateDate
single property: TotalSum
List<ProductId, ProductTitle, ProductPrice, Quantity, LineSum>
```

Does my imagination have root in reality?

I want to call the view as a partial view from _Layout.cshtml, like this:

```
<div class="container body-content">
    @Html.Partial("_ShoppingCart.cshtml")
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

Do I have to take the other models/views inside of @RenderBody() into concideration? Will they conflict with the partial view?

My attempt to write a View has resulted in pretty much just red squiggly lines:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyStore.Models.ViewModels.ViewModelShoppingCart>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <h4>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)</h4>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="item.ProductId">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Title)
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(Model => item.ShoppingCartItems)
            </td>
            <td>
                x <input type="text" size="1" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShoppingCartItemQuantity)" /> =
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LinePrice)
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
        <tr class="divider"><td colspan="4"></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><strong>Sum</strong></td>
            <td>
                <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Total)</strong>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Change `@model IEnumerable<MyStore.Models.ViewModels.ViewModelShoppingCart>` to `@model MyStore.Models.ViewModels.ViewModelShoppingCart`. You're showing one shopping cart, not multiple. a `ViewModelShoppingCart` has a `Title` property. An `IEnumerable<MyStore.Models.ViewModels.ViewModelShoppingCart>`  doesn't.

Comment: Then change `@foreach (var item in Model)` to `@foreach (var item in Model.ShoppingCartItems)`

Comment: Thank you. That worked! :) But now I'm faced with the unexpected model type exeption. One for this shopping cart and one for the main view (Products). Do I have to make ONE viewmodel which contains everything?

Comment: You could have one view that has a shopping cart as its model, and then part of that view iterates over the items and shows each one. Or you could create a partial view for the products. The main view passes the products to the partial view. You might even want a view that does nothing but render a single product. That can be helpful for reusability and consistency.